# IOS push notification delete

Tags: ios, notifications, apn

I use a phone gap [plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) and xcode 5.

Lets see the example of the problem:

The application is in background or closed.

1. I send the notification.
2. User sees the notification pop up, without clicking on it.
3. I send another notification.

If user open notification bar it will see two notification actually i want
to delete the previous some how and present to user only the second notification.

The eqvivalent in java is `NotificationManage.cancelAll();`

For now each/all notification i send are shown when user open notifications bar.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have (the app has) no control over that.

The user controls how many notifications they see in notification center. Notifications can be removed by the user and will be removed when acted upon (the app is opened from the notification).

Comment: Do you have any official reference that in ios it is not possible please?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;`
in the method `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. In this way notification center will be cleared.

Comment: As i checked the badge number has influence only on the number that appears on the app icon.

Comment: This is undocumented (AFAIK) but should clear the notifications - but only when the app is next run.

Comment: This cleans only the number on the icon but not all notifications.